# ThinkVantage Access Connection alternative?

Tags: internet-connection

I've used Access Connection with my previous Thinkpad laptop, but now I own a non-lenovo pc.
Is there any good alternative to manage and automatically switch network profiles?

Thanks

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: Just FYI, I believe you can still use Lenovo Access Connections. You can download it from Lenovo's website. Just Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your OS is Windows, have a look at netsetman.

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad, and I dropped Access Connections in favor of netsetman. I find it lighter and more intuitive. The free version comes with the ability to configure up to 6 different network profiles, using any of your network devices - more than enough for me. The paid version is unlimited.

Access Connections has some automated VPN configuration tools (which I never used) - I don't think netsetman can match this feature.

Comment: I'm trying NetSetMan, and seems good enough.

Since I need proxy configuration, I bought the pro, but alas it's missing ability to configure proxy authentication. 

Also VPN would be a great addition, but I can live without. 

Thanks!

Comment: BWT, since I need only one profile with proxy authentication, I'm going to fake it creating a local proxy with http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/