# Why can my computer still be able to ping other network card addresses except 127.0.0.1 when the network cable is unplugged?

Tags: windows-10, c#

my IP address = 192.168.1.1, and the sever ip address is 192.168.1.10. my question is After unplugging the end network cable, it can still be pinged. Only after the network config-uration is disabled, the alarm will be triggered. And the Wifi is off. I tried adding the network address to the permanent route, but it didn't work

Comment: Do you have both ethernet and wifi? If only one was unplugged, then the other will succeed. ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/845871/windows-ip-address-cached-even-after-cable-unplugged))

Comment: Only static IP is set, no WiFi is set. My previous network address was a static IP. Will it be affected if the network address is set to a static IP?

Comment: Static IP shouldn't matter? Which end of the cable are you unplugging - on the server side or on the client side?

Comment: on the server side

Comment: Are you pinging by IP or computer-name? What are the results of the ping (a screenshot might help)?